# Magento 2 Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException through exception, but didn't track anything in error log

Tags: magento2, error, log

When applying laygered navigation filter in my Magento 2, In **Developer Mode** I got this error,

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): sorry, something went wrong. You can find out more in the error log
```

But the problem is that nothing is tracked in whether the **Apache error log** or the **Magento log**. So I don't know how to diagnose the issue.

Any ideas on how to debug when seeing errors like this?

---

**Update**,

If I turn **Production Mode** on, the `Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException):` error mesesage is gone, and it displays an empty page, but I in developer tools in my browser it says "JavaScript seems to be disabled in your browser".

[image]

But I'm sure it's nothing to do with Javascript on my browser. I've tried with different browsers on different computers, I got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this error on two times.

- When Product collection is called.
- When Advance Search Collection is called.

**On classes**

- `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Advanced\Collection.`
- `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection.`

I guess that you have issue on collection  call.

I guess that you need to do an indexing.

Comment: I just did reindexing. I didn't help. Is there a way that I can see the error in log? I wonder why apache error log didn't track anything. I got the error when applying layered navigation in magento. but not all options i selected in the filter give me the error. for example if i use only price in the layered navigation then it's working fine. it's sizes, and some other option that gives errors.

Comment: I have look further on this issue, and you are right, it is the fulltext search gave the error. it's my 3rd part module that conflicted with Magento's Layered navigation.

Comment: which extension?

Comment: It's EaDesign's warehouse inventory module.
https://github.com/EaDesgin/magento2-warehouses/issues/13

I have disabled the fulltext search from this module, then Layered Navigation is working again.

Comment: @AmitBera i did indexing but still getting this error,i am using that mageplaza layered navigation

Comment: @sumeetbajaj Did you find solution for the issue, I am getting same issue

Comment: I'm getting this with Mageplaza Layered navigation, but the search module I'm using is Mirasvit. I wonder if there's a connection

Answer (score 1):

## ✅How to fix it

Modify the `Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation` module's existing code to use the `logger` as follows:

```
app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection.php::497-501
```

```
function _renderFiltersBefore(){
    ...
    try {
        $this->searchResult = $this->getSearch()->search($searchCriteria);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_logger->error( $e->getMessage() );  //   Add this line
        throw new LocalizedException(__('Sorry, something went wrong. You can find out more in the error log.'));
    }
    ...
}
```

---

## Result

Now useful information will be populated in Magento's `var/system.log`:

```
[2021-02-19 18:30:46] report.ERROR: Notice: Undefined index: match in app/code/Mything/Elasticsearch/Plugin/SearchAdapter/Query/Builder/Match.php on line 50 [] []
[2021-02-19 18:30:46] report.ERROR: Sorry, something went wrong. You can find out more in the error log. [] []
```

---

## Academic Reading

This error is specific to Magento sites using the `Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation` module.

I understand that for frontend users we would want a static & locally translated  message. However it seems very silly to catch an `Exception` but not log or render any information about the actual `Exception`. To make things debuggable, this implementation needed to be changed.

**What caused it (*for me*); your's will be different**:

I encountered Mageplaza's `LocalizedException` when creating a plugin on `afterBuild()` for this class:

```
Magento\Elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\Query\Builder\Match
```

The issue was caused by a very simple error in my own plugin's `afterBuild()` method (*for me, it was simply a `Notice` about a missing array key*). However due to Mageplaza's `try{}catch(){}` block throwing a static message in a `LocalizedException`, I did not have the information necessary to debug the underlying issue.

## Personal experience with this brand of modules

I've been involved with sites using Mageplaza modules from 2014 to 2021. Although some of their development staff is extremely talented (*Uri is great*), these types of best-practice missteps seem to arise semi-frequently regarding Mageplaza modules. Some of their implementations seem less-than-professional or not thoroughly finished for minor things like this and it commonly costs me hours of extra time. Some areas of their codebase remind me of when I leave a `//TO-DO:` comment marker in my own code to flag a better way to implement something later because I don't have time at the moment to do it right.

Comment: Your answer helped me to debug the errors at `system.log`